# Склейка изображений Python

Tags: python, pyqt, png, save, qpixmap

У меня есть большое изображение, которое разбито на мозаику из одинаковых по размеру кусочков. Имена в формате - <**`Номер строки`**>**`_`**<**`Номер столбца`**>.

Я хочу склеить их все в одно большое изображение, но не знаю как сделать. Изначально хотел сначала склеить отдельно строки, а уже их объединить в большое изображение, но не могу понять, как это реализовать.

---

**UPD**: Забыл добавить, что ещё одна проблема заключается в том, что фрагментов достаточно много (**`1104`**) и при этом каждый из них весит примерно по **`2.1`** Мб.

Comment: Вадим вам надо помочь из фрагментов составить многомерный список?

Comment: @S.Nick, нет, именно цельный файл из вот этих фрагментов

Comment: Вадим я добавил в свой ответ метод, который создает целый файл, проверьте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде чем запустить мой пример, убедитесь, что вы установили *PyQt5*

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

*PyQt* — реализация фреймворка *Qt* для языка *Python*.

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.Qt import * 
  
  
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
  
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        list_image = [
            ['image11.png', 'image21.png', 'image31.png'],
            ['image12.png', 'image22.png', 'image32.png'],
            ['image13.png', 'image23.png', 'image33.png'],
        ]
  
        button = QPushButton("Click my", self)
        button.setCheckable(True)
        button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        
        for row in range(len(list_image)):
            for column in range(len(list_image[0])):
                label = QLabel()
                label.setPixmap(QPixmap(list_image[row][column]))
                self.layout.addWidget(label, row+1, column+1)
                
        self.layout.setRowStretch(0, 1) 
        self.layout.setRowStretch(4, 1)        
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1) 
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(4, 1) 
        self.layout.addWidget(button, 6, 2)
        
    def button_clicked(self, state):
        if state:
            self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        else:
            self.layout.setSpacing(10)
        
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update:**

Вадим вам надо помочь из фрагментов составить многомерный список?

> нет, именно цельный файл из вот этих фрагментов

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.Qt import * 
  
  
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
  
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        list_image = [
            ['image11.png', 'image21.png', 'image31.png'],
            ['image12.png', 'image22.png', 'image32.png'],
            ['image13.png', 'image23.png', 'image33.png'],
        ]
  
        button = QPushButton("Click my", self)
        button.setCheckable(True)
        button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
        self.widget = QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.widget)
        
        for row in range(len(list_image)):
            for column in range(len(list_image[0])):
                label = QLabel()
                label.setPixmap(QPixmap(list_image[row][column]))
                self.layout.addWidget(label, row+1, column+1)
                
        self.layout.setRowStretch(0, 1) 
        self.layout.setRowStretch(4, 1)        
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1) 
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(4, 1) 
        
        self.layout_main = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(button)
        
    def button_clicked(self, state):
        if state:
            self.layout.setSpacing(0)
            QTimer.singleShot(10, self.save_image)
        else:
            self.layout.setSpacing(10)
            
    def save_image(self):
        fname = "q1334997.png"
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.widget.size())
        self.widget.render(QPainter(pixmap))
        pixmap.save(fname) 

        self.label_image = QLabel()
        self.label_image.setWindowTitle(f'{fname} !!!')
        self.label_image.setPixmap(QPixmap(fname))        
        self.label_image.show()
        
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**image11.png               image21.png    image31.png**

[image: image11.png] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**image12.png      image22.png     image32.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: image22.png] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**image13.png   image23.png   image33.png**

[image: image13.png] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]